# Efficient way to power and mod in ruby

Tags: ruby

i need to know the value of an power and mod of 3 values, such as:

```
print 1_299_709 ** 1_300_751 % 104_729
```

was there any ruby gems or faster way to compute this using ruby?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) and is used heavily in cryptography. Its fairly easy to write a modular exponentiation algorithm, a demonstration is in the wikipedia article listed above.

You can use the standard library openssl to achieve your goal:

```
require 'openssl'
1_299_709.to_bn.mod_exp(1_300_751, 104_729) # => 90827
```

Answer (score 12):

Since Ruby 2.5 modular exponentiation is built in:

```
print 1_299_709.pow(1_300_751, 104_729)
```

Comment: Awesome! [documentation link](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Integer.html#method-i-pow) for the curious